# Deciphering and printing a loop condtion

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, printing, scalar

Apologies for being newbie, I inherited perl code that I can not figure out, perhaps one of you can.

```
for ( @{$things} ){

...
}
```

I know arrays begin with @ and scalars begin with $.

I am not sure exactly what we are doing here, and attempts to print it out fail. What is the best way to print out `@{$things}` so I can figure out what this for loop is all about?

Comment: What language ? Perl perhaps ? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: @PaulR, " know arrays begin with @ and scalars begin with $."

Comment: Apologies, forgot to mention it was perl. Now I feel like that guy that asked what time the internet closes at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$things` is a reference to an array
`@{$things}` dereference this array

See this [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot. Now I understand more how to loop over an array with only a reference. Kudos.